# Combining array based on a key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'll be having some 9 dynamic arrays.
I would need to combine them considering a parameter for combining them which is ItemNumber.
Most of my arrays will have a single item except three arrays which might have more than one.

So suppose in below example.

```
var arr1 = [
  { 'IM_Id': 1, 'IM_Name': 'Hello', 'ItemNumber': 2001 },
  { 'IM_Id': 2, 'IM_Name': 'World', 'ItemNumber': 2002 }
];
var arr2 = [
  { 'FE_Id': 2, 'FE_Name': 'Wall',     'Code': 'XYZ',  'ItemNumber': 2001 },
  { 'FE_Id': 3, 'FE_Name': 'WallMart', 'Code': '009F', 'ItemNumber': 2002 }
];
var arr3 = [
  { 'FC_Id': 2, 'FC_Name': 'ABC',  'Value': 009, 'ItemNumber': 2001 },
  { 'FC_Id': 3, 'FC_Name': 'PQR',  'Value': 007, 'ItemNumber': 2001 },
  { 'FC_Id': 4, 'FC_Name': 'ABCD', 'Value': 004, 'ItemNumber': 2002 },
  { 'FC_Id': 5, 'FC_Name': 'PQRS', 'Value': 002, 'ItemNumber': 2002 }
];
```

In above array arr1 and arr2 has just one item with ItemNumber 2001 and same for ItemNumber 2002.
However arr3 has 2 items for both the item numbers.

So when creating resulting array the arrays with single item will be considered repeatedly to consider the other items of array with multiples.

So the resulting array will be something like below.

```
 var resultingArray = [
  { 'IM_Id': 1, 'IM_Name': 'Hello', 'FE_Id': 2, 'FE_Name': 'Wall', 'Code': 'XYZ',
    'FC_Id': 2, 'FC_Name': 'ABC', 'Value': 009 },
  { 'IM_Id': 1, 'IM_Name': 'Hello', 'FE_Id': 2, 'FE_Name': 'Wall', 'Code': 'XYZ',
    'FC_Id': 3, 'FC_Name': 'PQR', 'Value': 007 },
  { 'IM_Id': 2, 'IM_Name': 'World', 'FE_Id': 3, 'FE_Name': 'WallMart', 'Code': '009F',
    'FC_Id': 4, 'FC_Name': 'ABCD', 'Value': 004 },
  { 'IM_Id': 2, 'IM_Name': 'World', 'FE_Id': 3, 'FE_Name': 'WallMart', 'Code': '009F',
    'FC_Id': 5, 'FC_Name': 'PQRS', 'Value': 002 }
];
```

You can see that to consider the matching elements of arr3 with FC_Id=2 and FC_Id = 3 for ItemNumber 2001 the resulting array has repeated the items of arr1 and arr2 but with different arr3 items.

I have tried following code but it just gives me a single item with similar ItemNumber.

I might have multiple items for a single `ItemNumber` too.

```
function joinObjects() {
  var idMap = {}, key, property;
  // Iterate over arguments
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    // Iterate over individual argument arrays (aka json1, json2)
    for (var j = 0; j < arguments[i].length; j++) {
      var currentID = arguments[i][j]['ItemMasterNumber'];
      if (!idMap[currentID]) {
        idMap[currentID] = {};
      }
      // Iterate over properties of objects in arrays (aka id, name, etc.)
      for (key in arguments[i][j]) {
        idMap[currentID][key] = arguments[i][j][key];
      }
    }
  }
  // Push properties of idMap into an array
  var newArray = [];
  for (property in idMap) {
    newArray.push(idMap[property]);
  }
  return newArray;
}

var finalArray = joinObjects(arr1, arr2, arr3);
```

I will actually have 9 such arrays of which only 3 might have multiple items that is multiple items with same item number.

I am adding a sample example too with 6 such arrays.

```
var arr1 = [{'IM_Id': 1, 'IM_Name': 'Hello', 'ItemNumber': 2001}, {'IM_Id': 2, 'IM_Name': 'World', 'ItemNumber': 2002}];
            var arr2 = [{'FE_Id': 2, 'FE_Name': 'Wall', 'Code': 'XYZ', 'ItemNumber': 2001}, {'FE_Id': 3, 'FE_Name': 'WallMart', 'Code': '009F', 'ItemNumber': 2002}];
            var arr3 = [{'FC_Id': 2, 'FC_Name': 'ABC', 'Value': 009, 'ItemNumber': 2001},
                {'FC_Id': 3, 'FC_Name': 'PQR', 'Value': 007, 'ItemNumber': 2001},
                {'FC_Id': 4, 'FC_Name': 'ABCD', 'Value': 004, 'ItemNumber': 2002},
                {'FC_Id': 5, 'FC_Name': 'PQRS', 'Value': 002, 'ItemNumber': 2002}
            ];
            var arr4 = [{'OC_Id':6,'OC_Name':'Rai','OC_Price':'$30','ItemNumber': 2001},{'OC_Id': 7,'OC_Name':'Raj','OC_Price':'$60','ItemNumber': 2002}];
            var arr5 = [{'CH_Id':4,'CH_Name':'Sen','CH_Code':'LMN','ItemNumber': 2001},{'CH_Id':7,'CH_Name':'Ken','CH_Code':'IJK','ItemNumber': 2002}];
            var arr6 = [{'CO_Id':5,'CO_Name':'xyz','CO_Value':'qqq','ItemNumber': 2001},{'CO_Id':9,'CO_Name':'pqr','CO_Code':'LMN','ItemNumber': 2001}];
```

And the resulting array should be something like

```
var resultingArray = [
                {'IM_Id': 1, 'IM_Name': 'Hello', 'FE_Id': 2, 'FE_Name': 'Wall', 'Code': 'XYZ',
                    'FC_Id': 2, 'FC_Name': 'ABC', 'Value': 009,'OC_Id':6,'OC_Name':'Rai','OC_Price':'$30','CH_Id':4,'CH_Name':'Sen','CH_Code':'LMN',
                    'CO_Id':5,'CO_Name':'xyz','CO_Value':'qqq'
                    },
                {'IM_Id': 1, 'IM_Name': 'Hello', 'FE_Id': 2, 'FE_Name': 'Wall', 'Code': 'XYZ',
                    'FC_Id': 3, 'FC_Name': 'PQR', 'Value': 007,'OC_Id':6,'OC_Name':'Rai','OC_Price':'$30','CH_Id':4,'CH_Name':'Sen','CH_Code':'LMN',
                    'CO_Id':9,'CO_Name':'pqr','CO_Code':'LMN'
                },
                {'IM_Id': 2, 'IM_Name': 'World', 'FE_Id': 3, 'FE_Name': 'WallMart', 'Code': '009F',
                    'FC_Id': 4, 'FC_Name': 'ABCD', 'Value': 004,'OC_Id': 7,'OC_Name':'Raj','OC_Price':'$60','CH_Id':7,'CH_Name':'Ken','CH_Code':'IJK',
                    'CO_Id':"-",'CO_Name':'-','CO_Code':'-'

                },
                {'IM_Id': 2, 'IM_Name': 'World', 'FE_Id': 3, 'FE_Name': 'WallMart', 'Code': '009F',
                    'FC_Id': 5, 'FC_Name': 'PQRS', 'Value': 002,'OC_Id': 7,'OC_Name':'Raj','OC_Price':'$60','CH_Id':7,'CH_Name':'Ken','CH_Code':'IJK',
                    'CO_Id':"-",'CO_Name':'-','CO_Code':'-'

                }
```

Also, note arr6 has two items both with same item number 2001 and no elements for item number 2002.

In that case it's taking an empty or just a "-" in the resulting array last two elements.

Comment: the question looks familiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603443/combining-multiple-arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a function called `joinArrays()` which accepts infinite parameters where each parameter is an array.

This function loops through its arguments. If a car with the `ItemNumber` in the resulting array doesn't exist exist, we'll create an empty object in the resulting array. All of the cars details are added to this new object.

There are some instances where your car details have multiple values for the same ItemNumber. In this instance, I've just created an array containing all of these since this wasn't specified in the question.

```js
var arr1 = [
  { 'IM_Id': 1, 'IM_Name': 'Hello', 'ItemNumber': 2001 },
  { 'IM_Id': 2, 'IM_Name': 'World', 'ItemNumber': 2002 }
];
var arr2 = [
  { 'FE_Id': 2, 'FE_Name': 'Wall',     'Code': 'XYZ',  'ItemNumber': 2001 },
  { 'FE_Id': 3, 'FE_Name': 'WallMart', 'Code': '009F', 'ItemNumber': 2002 }
];
var arr3 = [
  { 'FC_Id': 2, 'FC_Name': 'ABC',  'Value': 009, 'ItemNumber': 2001 },
  { 'FC_Id': 3, 'FC_Name': 'PQR',  'Value': 007, 'ItemNumber': 2001 },
  { 'FC_Id': 4, 'FC_Name': 'ABCD', 'Value': 004, 'ItemNumber': 2002 },
  { 'FC_Id': 5, 'FC_Name': 'PQRS', 'Value': 002, 'ItemNumber': 2002 }
];

console.log(joinArrays(arr1, arr2, arr3));

function joinArrays() {
var resultingArray = [],
 itemNumbersAdded = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var argument = arguments[i];
    
    for (var j = 0; j < argument.length; j++) {
     var carDetails = argument[j];
        
        if (itemNumbersAdded.indexOf(carDetails.ItemNumber) === -1) {
         itemNumbersAdded.push(carDetails.ItemNumber);
            resultingArray[itemNumbersAdded.indexOf(carDetails.ItemNumber)] = {};
        }
        
        var resultingArrayCarDetails = resultingArray[itemNumbersAdded.indexOf(carDetails.ItemNumber)];
        
        for (var k = 0; k < Object.keys(carDetails).length; k++) {
         var carDetailName = Object.keys(carDetails)[k];
            
            if (resultingArrayCarDetails.hasOwnProperty(carDetailName) && carDetailName !== "ItemNumber") {
           if (!(resultingArrayCarDetails[carDetailName] instanceof Array)) {
                 resultingArrayCarDetails[carDetailName] = [resultingArrayCarDetails[carDetailName]]
                }
                
                resultingArrayCarDetails[carDetailName].push(carDetails[carDetailName]);
            } else {
             resultingArrayCarDetails[carDetailName] = carDetails[carDetailName];
            }
        }
    }
}

return resultingArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Toby but the output differs from the expected output.

Comment: The resulting array should be a merge of all the properties from other arrays.

Comment: @AahanaPatel Ah okay, sorry. So you want to combine all of the information from all of the arrays where the item number matches?

Comment: @AahanaPatel Check if https://jsfiddle.net/L1t1zqbn/ works? I'll update my answer

Comment: Toby,Thanks man, your answer looks promising but the result is not the expected pattern.Can you please have a look on the explanation.I have added some more explanation and I'll appreciate if you can help me out with this.

Comment: @AahanaPatel I'm still unsure what you mean. My answer should at least form a basis to get the problem sorted

Comment: Toby, you're right its just am a newbie to JS and this seems very complex to me.

Comment: @AahanaPatel If I'm right, please mark press the tick next to the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a doubly-nested loop to map over the source array items to the destination items.

```js
var arr1 = [
  { 'IM_Id': 1, 'IM_Name': 'Hello', 'ItemNumber': 2001 },
  { 'IM_Id': 2, 'IM_Name': 'World', 'ItemNumber': 2002 }
];
var arr2 = [
  { 'FE_Id': 2, 'FE_Name': 'Wall',     'Code': 'XYZ',  'ItemNumber': 2001 },
  { 'FE_Id': 3, 'FE_Name': 'WallMart', 'Code': '009F', 'ItemNumber': 2002 }
];
var arr3 = [
  { 'FC_Id': 2, 'FC_Name': 'ABC',  'Value': 009, 'ItemNumber': 2001 },
  { 'FC_Id': 3, 'FC_Name': 'PQR',  'Value': 007, 'ItemNumber': 2001 },
  { 'FC_Id': 4, 'FC_Name': 'ABCD', 'Value': 004, 'ItemNumber': 2002 },
  { 'FC_Id': 5, 'FC_Name': 'PQRS', 'Value': 002, 'ItemNumber': 2002 }
];
var arr4 = [
  { 'OC_Id': 6, 'OC_Name': 'Rai', 'OC_Price': '$30', 'ItemNumber': 2001 },
  { 'OC_Id': 7, 'OC_Name': 'Raj', 'OC_Price': '$60', 'ItemNumber': 2002 }
];
var arr5 = [
  { 'CH_Id': 4, 'CH_Name': 'Sen', 'CH_Code': 'LMN', 'ItemNumber': 2001 },
  { 'CH_Id': 7, 'CH_Name': 'Ken', 'CH_Code': 'IJK', 'ItemNumber': 2002 }
];
var arr6 = [
  { 'CO_Id': 5, 'CO_Name': 'xyz', 'CO_Value': 'qqq', 'ItemNumber': 2001 },
  { 'CO_Id': 9, 'CO_Name': 'pqr', 'CO_Code':  'LMN', 'ItemNumber': 2001 }
];

var arr7 = merge(arr3, 'ItemNumber', [arr1, arr2, arr4, arr5, arr6]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr7, null, 2));

function merge(target, prop, srcArr) {
  return target.map(item => {
    srcArr.forEach(arr => {
      arr.forEach(src => {
        if (src[prop] === item[prop]) {
          Object.keys(src).forEach(key => item[key] = src[key])
        }
      })
    })
    return item;
  });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mr Polywhirl.But in my case I have 9 arrays of which I'll have 3 with multiple records.In that case how should I program the above logic.

Comment: @Aahana Patel _"9 arrays of which I'll have 3 with multiple records"_ Can you provide an example of that data? Not sure I follow...

Comment: Polywhirl Thanks and I have added an example with 6 such arrays.

Comment: @AahanaPatel Just add more arrays to the source array list. I just added the additional arrays to the list.

Comment: @Polywhirl, thanks a lot! But there's one issue with the output.If you see its only considering the second element of arr6.You can see my example of how actually it should consider both the elements of arr6 too similar to arr3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.assign:

```js
var arr1 = [{'IM_Id': 1, 'IM_Name': 'Hello', 'ItemNumber': 2001}, {'IM_Id': 2, 'IM_Name': 'World', 'ItemNumber': 2002}];
            var arr2 = [{'FE_Id': 2, 'FE_Name': 'Wall', 'Code': 'XYZ', 'ItemNumber': 2001}, {'FE_Id': 3, 'FE_Name': 'WallMart', 'Code': '009F', 'ItemNumber': 2002}];
            var arr3 = [{'FC_Id': 2, 'FC_Name': 'ABC', 'Value': 009, 'ItemNumber': 2001},
                {'FC_Id': 3, 'FC_Name': 'PQR', 'Value': 007, 'ItemNumber': 2001},
                {'FC_Id': 4, 'FC_Name': 'ABCD', 'Value': 004, 'ItemNumber': 2002},
                {'FC_Id': 5, 'FC_Name': 'PQRS', 'Value': 002, 'ItemNumber': 2002}
            ];
            
            var resultArr= [];
            arr1.forEach( function(item){
              arr2.forEach( function(item2){
                if( item2.ItemNumber === item.ItemNumber)
                     {
                     //var obj = Object.assign( {} ,item2, item);
                     arr3.forEach(function(item3){
                        if( item3.ItemNumber === item.ItemNumber)
                           {
                           var obj2 = Object.assign( {},item, item2, item3);
                           resultArr.push(obj2);
                           }
                        });
                    }
              });
            });
            
            console.log(JSON.stringify( resultArr ));
```